# Higcharts Gantt chart with table and sub-tasks

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

How can I have collapsible sub-tasks while using the table on the left? If I remove the table columns then it works fine. This is the example from the official website, unfortunately there is no demo for my case. Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is the fiddle I've played with: https://jsfiddle.net/sharvadze/4h80gdts/1/

```
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Left Axis as Table'
},

xAxis: {
    tickPixelInterval: 70
},

yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    grid: {
        enabled: true,
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        columns: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Project'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Assignee'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{point.assignee}'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Est. days'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var point = this.point,
                        days = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
                        number = (point.x2 - point.x) / days;
                    return Math.round(number * 100) / 100;
                }
            }
        }, {
            labels: {
                format: '{point.start:%e. %b}'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Start date'
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'End date'
            },
            offset: 30,
            labels: {
                format: '{point.end:%e. %b}'
            }
        }]
    }
},

tooltip: {
    xDateFormat: '%e %b %Y, %H:%M'
},

series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [{
            id: 'test',
        start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 18, 8),
        end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
        name: 'Start prototype',
        assignee: 'Richards',
        y: 0
    }, {
            parent: 'test',
        start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 20, 8),
        end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 24, 16),
        name: 'Develop',
        assignee: 'Michaels',
        y: 1
    }, {
        start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
        end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
        name: 'Prototype done',
        assignee: 'Richards',
        y: 2
    }, {
        start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 27, 8),
        end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 3, 16),
        name: 'Test prototype',
        assignee: 'Richards',
        y: 3
    }, {
        start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 23, 8),
        end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 15, 16),
        name: 'Run acceptance tests',
        assignee: 'Halliburton',
        y: 4
    }]
}]
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is not supported in Highcharts Gantt yet. You can add this idea to the user voice page and if it gets enough votes it will be added: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Comment: To anyone who bumped to this question, I noticed that there are no user voice request for this yet so I made one, perhaps you can help to upvote this so it can be seen and hopefully added in the future. Here is the [link](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/39780268-multiple-collpasible-treegrid-gantt-yaxis)

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Even I'm trying to do it but facing the same issue. Is there any way you have completed this task by any other way?

Comment: @Geeky I ended up using different library: dhtmlxGantt

Comment: @GeorgeSharvadze which library you are using now for subtasks in a table?

Comment: @AbrarAhmad this is the one: https://dhtmlx.com/blog/use-dhtmlxgantt-vue-js-framework-demo/